# J2ME Emulator not responding

Tags: java, emulation, netbeans-7, midlet

am trying to do a simple hello world program in J2ME, I am using Netbeans 7.2.1  on ubuntu 12.04.
   package helloworld;

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

/**
 * @author mashombo
*/

public class Midlet extends MIDlet {

private TextBox tb;
private Display display = null;

public void helloworld(){
tb = new TextBox("Hello world Midlets"," -samboga", 100, 0);
}
public void startApp() {
    if(display == null){
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    display.setCurrent(tb);
    }
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}


}
```

When I try to run the above code the emulator does not respond I try to press the launch     button on the right side of the emulator nothing happens. Here is the output when I run

```
Starting emulator in execution mode
Running with storage root /home/mashombo/j2mewtk/2.5.2/appdb/DefaultGrayPhone
Running with locale: en_ZA.UTF-8
/dev/dsp: No such file or directory
Running in the identified_third_party security domain
```

Can you please help is there something i am missing? I am new to Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know /dev/dsp is a device to work with OSS. Try to load it with this command:

```
modprobe snd-pcm-oss
```